# Keep App Activity full screen when Sending the User to Another App

Tags: android

im using the following code to make an Activity Full Screen. All is ok. However if i send the user to another App such as Gmail from the same Activity that is full screen the Status and Navigation bars appear and the Activity is losing full screen. Is there a way to code it not to do that?. I had a look here [Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) but i didn't spot anything to help me.

Thanks

**minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 23**

Activity is a **ViewPager**

**Code used to achieve full screen**

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

Comment: Are you trying to ensure that your activity remains full screen, or that the third-party activity you're launching is also full screen?

Comment: @Kevin Krumwiede -- i want my Activity to remain Full screen. At the moment if i launch another App such as Gmail from my Activity the Status and Nav bars appear for some reason and the Activity is not full screen anymore. The other App (Gmail) is ok

Answer (score 0):

I must have skipped this part in the guide. All ok now. The Activity  returns back to full screen when it has focus again

[image]

**Code**

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);}
```